How to apply dynamic route color for a navigation in Mapbox?
I'm using Mapbox in combination with GraphHopper to implement custom navigation on Android (I'm particularly using this sample app: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-navigation-example).
This, as any typical navigation app, paints the whole route as a blue line on the map. And I'd like it not to be blue, but dynamically colored. How to do that?
For instance I will paint some fragments as red if there's a traffic jam in that area.
